# OpenStack, How to create nova filter scheduler?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-python-api

I am new to OpenStack.

I have gone through the document as https://docs.openstack.org/nova/wallaby/user/filter-scheduler.html suggests.
But I am not getting how and where to put the code.

Do I need to install the package I created as mentioned in the document?

Kindly guide me through the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple steps required to add a new filter. You first need to create your own python package. You then need to install it on the system running OpenStack and add it to `enabled_filters` and `available_filters` under the `filter_scheduler` section of the nova configuration.

Assuming you create a package named `nova_filter_example` with a filter named `RandomFilter`, you would need to change your `nova.conf` to look something like this.

```
[filter_scheduler]
available_filters = nova.scheduler.filters.all_filters
available_filters = nova_filter_example.RandomFilter
enabled_filters = ComputeFilter,RandomFilter
```

I created a small example example package that might help. You can find it [here](https://github.com/eandersson/nova-filter-example). It includes steps on how to deploy and test the custom filter in a [devstack](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/) environment.